# SQL - is it possible to replace value in primary key for uuid?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a test table having say ID field (primary key) with values like (abcd1234, mnop5678). Now I want to replace all values of ID to introduce hyphens so that the value becomes (abcd-1234, mnop-5678). How do I do it using SQL)?

PS: The real use case is that the ID field used to be an alphanumeric value and is  now changed to [uuid format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) (having multiple hyphens in 8-4-4-4-12 format) Ask is to convert the existing data so as to avoid doing a truncate and reload of data as it contains millions of rows. Sorry for any typos, typing using mobile.

Comment: in sql server you can do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: `abcd-1234` is not a valid UUID. And if you are **really** using UUIDs you should not store them as a VARCHAR (with "a format") but use the native UUID data type your database product provides. Which saves space and is - depending on the actual DBMS - probably a lot more efficient than a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL Solution:
Suppose we have a table test1 where primary key is of varchar type, refer below table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
 `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Inserting sample records:

```
INSERT INTO `test1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('abcd1234', 'abcd');
INSERT INTO `test1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('mnop5678', 'mnop');
```

Now performing update query, where we are considering ID field format should be first 4 characters are letter, 5th character is -(hyphen) & then after numbers.

```
UPDATE `test1` SET `id` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`id`, 1, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(`id`, 5)) WHERE 1;
```

Have excluded where clause here, because need to do update operation on complete table.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a tonne for clear, concise and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

A sketch using some pseudo SQL dialect, as you didn't tag your DBMS:

1. You should first create a new column in the table with an UUID type.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t
         ADD (new_id uuid);
   ```
2. Then fill it with GUID.

   ```
   UPDATE t
          SET new_id = new_uuid();
   ```
3. Then alter all tables that reference the table as well.

   ```
   ALTER u
         ADD (new_t uuid);
   ...
   ```
4. Update them as well.

   ```
   UPDATE u
          SET new_t = (SELECT t.new_id
                              FROM t
                              WHERE t.id = u.t);
   ```
5. Drop the old column in the referencing tables.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE u
               DROP t;
   ...
   ```
6. Drop the column in the table.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t
               DROP id;
   ```
7. Rename the column in the table.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t
               RENAME new_id TO id;
   ```
8. Rename the column in the referencing tables.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE u
               RENAME new_t TO t;
   ...
   ```
9. Reintroduce the constraints on the table.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE t
               ADD (PRIMARY KEY (id));
   ```
10. Reintroduce the constraints on the referencing tables.

    ```
    ALTER TABLE u
                ADD (FOREIGN KEY (t)
                                 REFERENCES t
                                            (id));
    ```

You might also need to reindex the columns depending on the indexes you had on the old columns.